# Can't link boost file system with Qt creator

Tags: boost, linker, qmake

I need to use boost file system but under windows(cl 2010 express) i have some linker errors.
I use Qt creator and qmake and don't link explicit.The only think that i do is to give include and lib path

```
win32 {

    BOOSTHOME = C:/boost

    INCLUDEPATH += $$BOOSTHOME\\boost_1_47

    LIBS += -L$$BOOSTHOME\\boost_1_47\\lib
}
```

When I'm trying to build I get this error:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const * & __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet(void)" (?wchar_t_codecvt_facet@path@filesystem3@boost@@CAAAPBV?$codecvt@GDH@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem3@boost@@SAABV?$codecvt@GDH@std@@XZ)
```

I get two more, similar to that.
I have similar problem with libarchive but when i linking dynamically all is alright
What i must do to link correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows and msvc 2010 compiler must add define

```
DEFINES += BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
```

and after that link your boost lib with

```
LIBS += -lyourboostlib
```